# How to fix occasional EINVAL error when calling pthread_create

Tags: c, linux, pthreads, valgrind

### The Problem

When I create a detached thread using the code below, `pthread_create` will sometimes return EINVAL. I would like to know why this is happening and what I should do to fix it. When the error occurs, the code below will print the following line:

> Error creating thread. errno = 22: Invalid argument

### What I've Tried

I have only observed this issue when running my code in [valgrind](http://www.valgrind.org/). Even then, it only sometimes produces this error. Thus, I am inclined to think timing is a factor. I do not think I have a race condition, as this function does not rely on any shared data. Perhaps I have an issue with how I'm using the stack? I've been unsuccessful in discovering any helpful clues from the man pages, except that EINVAL means "Invalid settings in 'attr'."

I am running my application on Ubuntu 14.04.

### The Code

```
/**
 * Creates a detached thread to receive data from the socket referred to by
 * sockfd.
 */
void recieve_async(int sockfd) {
    pthread_t receive_thread;
    pthread_attr_t attr;
    int error = pthread_attr_init(&attr);
    if (error != 0) {
        printf("attr_init failed. errno = %d: %s\n", error, strerror(error));
    }
    error = pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&attr, PTHREAD_CREATE_DETACHED);
    if (error != 0) {
        printf("attr_setdetachstate failed. errno = %d: %s\n", error,
               strerror(error));
    }
    error = pthread_create(&receive_thread, &attr, receive, (void *)sockfd);
    if (error != 0) {
        printf("Error creating thread. errno = %d: %s\n", error,
               strerror(error));
        exit(1);
    }
    pthread_attr_destroy(&attr);
}
```

Comment: *The function heap_int merely copies sockfd to the heap and returns a pointer to that location on the heap; it's not of much interest here.*  You're asking this question because you don't know what's wrong. Since you don't know what's wrong, you can't know what is and what isn't of interest.

Comment: ... and in fact, I'm *very* interested in `heap_int()`, at least to rule it out as a possible contributing cause.  Its return value seems the only argument to `pthread_create()` whose validity might vary.

Comment: However, your code should certainly verify that `pthread_attr_init()` and `pthread_attr_setdetachstate()` both succeed.  Their failure seems unlikely, but that it not a license to assume such failures won't happen.

Comment: @JohnBollinger All values are value as that argument to pthread_create. It's only passed through to the thread function.

Comment: Is it possible that `pthread_attr_init` or `pthread_attr_setdetachstate` returned an error?

Comment: I don't see your point, @immibis.  The OP receives an `EINVAL` from `pthread_create`, so it seems natural to suppose that one of the arguments to that function is invalid.  The return value of `heap_int()` looks like the most likely suspect to me.

Comment: Josh: note that if the only point is to convey an `int` value to the thread, then the conventional technique is simply to *cast* it to `void *` on the calling side, and cast it back in the thread function -- no dynamic allocation involved.

Comment: I have updated the post per some of your suggestions. I have replaced the call to `heap_int()` with a cast as suggested by @JohnBollinger. Additionally, I now check all return values. The behavior remains unchanged. The **only** error that is printed is the error I noted in the post.

Comment: @johnBollinger There is no possible way that `pthread_create` can return `EINVAL` because of the 4th parameter, because there are no invalid values for that parameter. The documentation says that it can return EINVAL if parameter 2 is invalid, which is why I suggested checking for errors from the `pthread_attr` functions.

Comment: Thank you @immibis, you're right.  I just didn't track the way you phrased it the first time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out this is a [bug in Valgrind](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=216124). The error that should *really* be reported is EAGAIN.

The function `receive_async` gets called several times per second. Even though I'm creating detached threads, Valgrind's virtual environment runs much, much slower than the native environment. So the situation was that I was creating threads faster than Valgrind could destroy them. Valgrind imposes a limit on the number of threads it can work with, and the default limit is 500.

I was able to monitor the number of threads my application was using with the command `watch ps -o nlwp <pid>`. When running it in Valgrind, the number of threads kept on growing, up to 500. When running outside of Valgrind, this number is much more reasonable (around 4) and does not grow indefinitely.

Comment: You might maybe try with --fair-sched=yes valgrind option. This ensures a better fairness between threads, which might help.

Comment: @phd That's not a bad idea, I'll have to give it a shot. I was actually still able to use Valgrind, I just had to be cautious of the amount of data I was pumping through my application. (Too much data = too many threads, in my case.)